# Helm Template Processing Order

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to figure out the precise processing order for templates within Helm (v3.8.1 and newer). Specifically, I'm looking for the order in which individual files are processed - if any.

I'm trying to figure out the best means to render some common-use values based on child charts' values. I have some subcharts that will need to interoperate, and I'm aware of the availability of the "global" map in order to publish values consumable by all charts.  I've not tested modifying the contents of "global" programmatically, but I expect this should be possible.

Regardless, what I'm getting at is that using static variables defined in values.yaml (global, specifically, or even subcharts' value overrides) may not be enough in order to achieve the interoperation I need for all of these subcharts.

Specifically, I would like for each subchart, as it's processed, to compute specific values that could be consumed for interoperation and then publish them to the "global" map (i.e.  global.subchart1.someValue, global.subchart2.someOtherValue, etc).

For instance: one of my subcharts is an LDAP provider, but an external LDAP could also be used, so the LDAP URL is something that needs to be "computed" to either be the external one (manually-specified), or the internal component's one.

This type of modification would allow me to consume those values (if available) wherever interoperation is required, via a single source of truth.

I'm looking for something like this:

1. Parse the top-level chart's Chart.yaml
2. Parse and process the top-level chart's non-template files (_* files)
3. Repeat the prior two steps for all subcharts, recursively
4. Parse the top-level chart's values.yaml
5. Parse and process/render the top-level chart's remaining template files
6. Repeat the prior two steps for all subcharts, recursively

Ideally, also including the order in which files are processed (I'm currently presuming they're processed alphabetically).

I realize this is probably not the ideal scenario, but I do want the ability for each subchart to be able to export information akin to "my service is exported on this port, with this user and password" (yes, I'm aware that secrets would likely be required here, etc...), or "this is the search DN for the LDAP users", etc.

Comment: Helm has an [extremely limited ability for subcharts to publish values back to the parent](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#importing-child-values-via-dependencies) and I don't think it can send back computed values.  I've usually seen the workflow you describe implemented with basically assertions on names; "I know the chart will produce a Secret named `{{ .Release.Name }}-subchart-credentials` so I'll consume that in the parent".

Comment: Yeah that's what the "global" object is for.  By understanding the exact "execution" (if you will) lifecycle then I can adopt a pattern where an "initializer" of sorts can be executed to populate those meant-to-be-shared interoperability values such that other charts can consume them.

The intent is, of course, to make the interop values optional in favor of defaults, but it's adding them properly and "correctly" that I'm working on ...

Comment: You can't change `.Values` or `.Values.global` either. You might see if you can use named templates to construct some of these values (which won't be order specific).  Helm should produce equivalent output regardless of the order in which it runs things.